# Can a Racket macro expand to nothing?

Tags: macros, racket

How can we write a `nothing` macro that expands the following lines as described in their comments?

```
(nothing + 1 2) ; -> (+ 1 2)
(+ 1 nothing 2) ; -> (+ 1 2)
(nothing)       ; ->         ; (just a blank line)
```

Something like the following would work if the occurrences  of `#'0` could be replaced with "the empty syntax", if such a thing exists.

```
(define-syntax (nothing stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(nothing) #'0]
    [(nothing body ...) #'(body ...)]
    [nothing #'0]))
```

So I suppose the question could be, "how do you represent empty syntax in racket?", but this is the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of "empty syntax". The closest you can get, is to produce an expression that does nothing. For example `(void)` or `(begin)` depending on the context.